# SslStream.BeginRead Method example

Tags: c#, networking, ssl

Regarding this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.beginread.aspx

Is there any code example on how to actually implement this method?

Any link will be appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a lot of work modifying the "SslStream Class" example code to use BeginRead/BeginWrite instead of Read/Write?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx